# Ajax return value using with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm having some problems making my function structure. Would appreciate any help.

First this function should delete map markers once **OnChange** event is triggered from **index.php**.
And send post values to **xmlmapquery.php** for data retrieval. 
once retrieved, The data should be stored back to my **index.php** in `<div id='content'>`

```
function filter()
{ 
   for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
   }
   markersArray.length = 0;

   var lgu = $('#lgu').val();
   var category = $('#category').val();
   var type = $('#type').val();
   $.get('xmlmapquery.php', { filter: lgu, filter2: category, filter3: type},function(data){
        $('#content').text(data);
   )};
};
```

Now this is **xmlmapquery.php**

```
<?php  
  include('connection_db.php');
  // Start XML file, create parent node
  $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
  $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
  $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

  if(isset($_POST['filter']) && isset($_POST['filter2']) && isset($_POST['filter3'])){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE type='".$_POST['filter']."' and type='".$_POST['filter2']."'
                                        and type='".$_POST['filter3']."'";
  } 
  // Select all the rows in the markers table
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$result) {  
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  } 

  header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

  // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
  while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
    $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  } 
  echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Would appreciate help on this. currently the function is **NOT** working even deleting the markers is not working. Once i get this thing working I will add more commands to the function that would get data and create new markers for my map. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your browser error console say anything about the JavaScript? That seems to be the root of your problem.  Note also that this script is vulnerable to SQL injection. At a minimum, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of those `$_POST` query inputs. Ideally though, consider switching to a newer API that supports prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO.  The `mysql_*()` functions will be deprecated in the next major PHP version 5.5

Comment: Error console  not helping. I was thinking i have a problem with my structure because I'm new with javascript, The inputs are from `<select>` elements I think they would be secure.

Comment: No they are _not_ secure. Although a casual user cannot easily change the values, anyone with basic knowledge of HTTP _can_ submit any values they want to your handling script. Anyone with an open browser DOM inspector can change the values.  The PHP script has no idea whether it is receiving input from your form or from any other specially crafted HTTP request - you _must_ sanitize those inputs.

Comment: That's not really secure, I could post anything I'd like to your server and have it inserted directly into the DB query, which could mean that I could completely mess up your DB or gain access to the server. Did you place a simple console.log in the success function of that ajax call to see if there is any data returned, and did you also try the same inside the filter function, to check that it's actually executed ?

Comment: I see, I will use `mysql_real_escape_string()` But I'll move to MySQLi In the near future. As i said I'm new to javascript I will try that console.log. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: At first the delete markers was working once I added the code for the http request. No response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your script logic is ok, and no `die()` or other php methods are returning null or false (anyway you should see in your browser console).

Things to do are:

1 - check firebug/chrome/browser console when launching request (if the request is hidden in some way use the "save" request method in console to check that)

2 - use `var_dump($dom->saveXML());` instead of `echo $dom->saveXML();`

3 - check server/php logs when possible

4 - be sure your request uirl is complete and working and i'm referring to `$.get('xmlmapquery.php');`

if you follow this line of debugging, unless ghosts doesn't exists, you will be able to run your script easly.

Hope it will help